# Column formatting changes vertical alignment

Tags: css, json, formatting

I followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) Microsoft guide on column formatting and made the changes I need to get it to work on 3 of my columns. Specifically I am using the bits on "Conditional formatting based on the value in a text or choice field (advanced)" and "Add an action button to a field (advanced)" not that I think it matters.

The issue I get is that the display for these formatted columns is now vertically aligned at the top of the cell rather than being in the center - how do I fix this?

OK, further clarification - it works fine in Chrome, doesn't work in Internet Explorer.